# Restart CCDIrector cause weird error

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I  am trying to restart my CCDirector of my game. But i have and error.

Fit of all this is my code in my menu [my menu its with XIB]:

```
- (void) retryGame:(NSNotification *)notif {
    [menu2Game.view removeFromSuperview];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] end];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] release];

    [self startGame:play];
}
```

And it give me and EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Just when I do it two times. The first one works perfectly...

But if remove

```
[self startGame:play];
```

I will be returned to the menu and I click to the button play and I could dod it infinite times and it works!

My quit its like that and i t works i try it like 20 times.

```
- (void) quitGame:(NSNotification *)notif {
    [menu2Game.view removeFromSuperview];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] end];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] release];

    //Restart Animations
    [logo setFrame:CGRectMake(239, 119, 1, 1)];
    [play setFrame:CGRectMake(-233, play.frame.origin.y, play.frame.size.width, play.frame.size.height)];
    [options setFrame:CGRectMake(-233, options.frame.origin.y, options.frame.size.width, options.frame.size.height)];
    [extras setFrame:CGRectMake(-233, extras.frame.origin.y, extras.frame.size.width, extras.frame.size.height)];
    [GC setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 300, 1, 1)];

    [self viewDidLoad];
}
```

//In my viewdidLoad I only have animation

What could be the problem? i try to do it with a delay [perfomselector] but its the same problem... Just if I return to the menu and click play I could play again. No matter the velocity, you could click play, pause, quit, play,pause, quit, etc... and the game go perfectly

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

CCDirector is a singleton, you should NOT send it the release message!

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] release];
```

It is perfectly fine not to do that. For what it's worth, CCDirector startAnimation and stopAnimation are more realiable ways of stopping Cocos2D temporarily.

Comment: I got the same problems i will post more info... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Same problem

```
- (void) retryGame:(NSNotification *)notif {
    [menu2Game.view removeFromSuperview];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] end];
    //[[CCDirector sharedDirector] release];

    [self startGame:play];
}
```

Start Game

```
 - (IBAction)startGame:(id)sender {


    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(quitGame:) name:@"quitGame" object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(retryGame:) name:@"retryGame" object:nil];

    CCDirector *director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];

    // Init the View Controller
    menu2Game = [[Menu2Game alloc] initWithNibName:@"Menu2Game" bundle:nil];
    menu2Game.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;

    //
    // Create the EAGLView manually
    //  1. Create a RGB565 format. Alternative: RGBA8
    //  2. depth format of 0 bit. Use 16 or 24 bit for 3d effects, like CCPageTurnTransition
    //
    //
    EAGLView *glView = [EAGLView viewWithFrame:[self.view bounds]
                                   pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGB565   // kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8
                                   depthFormat:0                        // GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16_OES
                        ];

    // attach the openglView to the director
    [director setOpenGLView:glView];

    // Enables High Res mode (Retina Display) on iPhone 4 and maintains low res on all other devices
    //  if( ! [director enableRetinaDisplay:YES] )
    //      CCLOG(@"Retina Display Not supported");


    [director setAnimationInterval:1.0/60];
    [director setDisplayFPS:YES];


    // make the OpenGLView a child of the view controller
    [menu2Game setView:glView];

    // make the View Controller a child of the main window
    [self.view addSubview: menu2Game.view];

    // Default texture format for PNG/BMP/TIFF/JPEG/GIF images
    // It can be RGBA8888, RGBA4444, RGB5_A1, RGB565
    // You can change anytime.
    [CCTexture2D setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat:kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888];

    // Assusme PVR images have the alpha channel premultiplied
    [CCTexture2D PVRImagesHavePremultipliedAlpha:YES];

    // Run the intro Scene
    if ([director runningScene] == NULL) {
        [[CCDirector sharedDirector] runWithScene:[Game scene]];
    }else{
        [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[Game scene]];
    }
}
```

If i comment [self startGame:play]; the error never appears

Errror apears in here

CCTextureAtlas.m [Cocos 2d]

```
#if CC_TEXTURE_ATLAS_USE_TRIANGLE_STRIP
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, (GLsizei) n*6, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, (GLvoid*) (start*6*sizeof(indices_[0])) );
#else
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, (GLsizei) n*6, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, (GLvoid*) (start*6*sizeof(indices_[0])) );
```